# Getting javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException when calling API from android app

Tags: java, android, ssl

I am facing a really weird error and app behavior.

I am using Identity Server 4 on server .net core API and AppAuth in my android app.

Everything worked fine with User1 untill I added User2 on my Identity Server 4.
I logged in normally, got access token, refresh token, claims and when I call Api to fetch data I got 
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`
 Which doesn't make sense.

1. It works fine when I log in as User1
2. On my server I have valid Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate

I tried:

- Calling API from Postman using access token I got for User2( it
  worked, I got the data)
- Clearing Shared Preferences on the phone
- Trying from different phone installing app for the first time
- Trying with new user User3(got the same result as User2)

I assume, because I got data from API and User Claims from userinfo endpoint from IS that its Android issue.
I can't really find out what is causing error.
Here is relevant code:

```
@MainThread
private void fetchInventories() {
    mAuthStateManager.getCurrent().performActionWithFreshTokens(mAuthService, this::fetchInventories);
}

@WorkerThread
private void fetchInventories(String accessToken, String idToken, AuthorizationException ex) {
    Log.i("INVENTORY", "Fetching Inventories");
    //runOnUiThread(() -> displayLoadingBar());
    if (ex != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Token refresh failed when fetching inventories");
        return;
    }

    URL inventoryEndpoint;
    try {
        inventoryEndpoint = new URL(AuxilliaApp.UserClaims.getInventoryClaims().getInventoryLocation()+"/inventories");
    } catch (MalformedURLException urlEx) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to construct inventories endpoint URL", urlEx);
        return;
    }

    mExecutor.submit(() -> {
        try {
            final InventoryActivity activity = mActivityReference.get();
            HttpURLConnection conn =
                    (HttpURLConnection) inventoryEndpoint.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            String response = Okio.buffer(Okio.source(conn.getInputStream())).readString(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            mInventoryItems.set(new JSONArray(response));
            mInventoryAdapter = new ListViewInventoryAdapter(activity, mInventoryItems.get());
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mInventoryList.setAdapter(mInventoryAdapter);
                    mInventoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            mInventoryList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Inventory selectedItem = (Inventory) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, InventoryEntriesActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Inventory", selectedItem);
                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Network error when querying inventory endpoint", ioEx);
        } catch (JSONException jsonEx) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse inventory response");
        }
    });
}
```

And here is exception I got (only when logged as User2, User1 works fine):

```
E/InventoryActivity: Network error when querying inventory endpoint
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:368)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:1510)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:1458)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1413)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1700)
        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:133)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:466)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:371)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:438)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:247)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
        at rs.co.ines.auxillia.inventory.InventoryActivity.lambda$fetchInventories$0$InventoryActivity(InventoryActivity.java:179)
        at rs.co.ines.auxillia.inventory.-$$Lambda$InventoryActivity$3H-9hA4vU25grEofstNCoXP43Kk.run(lambda)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
     Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:546)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:427)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:491)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:387)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:361)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:290)
        at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
        at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:178)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:617)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:364)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:1510) 
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:1458) 
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1413) 
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1700) 
        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:133) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:466) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:371) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:438) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:247) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java) 
        at rs.co.ines.auxillia.inventory.InventoryActivity.lambda$fetchInventories$0$InventoryActivity(InventoryActivity.java:179) 
        at rs.co.ines.auxillia.inventory.-$$Lambda$InventoryActivity$3H-9hA4vU25grEofstNCoXP43Kk.run(lambda) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762) 
     Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.verifyChain(TrustManagerImpl.java:546) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:427) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:491) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:387) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:361) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:290) 
        at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94) 
        at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:178) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:617) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:364) 
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectTls(Connection.java:1510) 
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:1458) 
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1413) 
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1700) 
        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:133) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:466) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:371) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:438) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:247) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210) 
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java) 
        at rs.co.ines.auxillia.inventory.InventoryActivity.lambda$fetchInventories$0$InventoryActivity(InventoryActivity.java:179) 
        at rs.co.ines.auxillia.inventory.-$$Lambda$InventoryActivity$3H-9hA4vU25grEofstNCoXP43Kk.run(lambda) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to this nonsense.

My claims were missing port in api url location so i got some other certiificate...
I found that by stepping into every single method called on http request and found which certificate i got from server.

Sorry guys.